Forward Filling a column in Kusto
I have the following query:
let table = MyMaterialisedView
| extend Value= iff(isnan(Value), double(null), Value) //replacing NANs with Nulls to avoid issues when calculating the Average
| order by ObjectAndId asc, ['10MinBin'] asc 
| scan declare (val: real) with
(
    step s1: true =>  val = iff(ObjectAndId == s1.ObjectAndId , iff(isempty(Value), s1.val, Value), Value);
)
| extend Value = val
| project-away val, ObjectAndId ;
table

What I'm doing here is basically querying my materialised view and replacing the null values with the latest non-null value for each ObjectAndId group. I'm using the scan operator as suggested by the Kusto documentation here
This forward fills the values as expected. the problem I have is that this function has a very high memory consumption and it's because I have a very large dataset. How can I improve the logic to forward fill my dataset?
Thank you

Hard to tell from just your query, but I'm assuming your table looks something similar to this?
let Events = datatable (Time: timespan, EventId: string, Value:string) [
    0m, "A", "1",
    1m, "B", "5",
    2m, "A", "",
    3m, "C", "",
    4m, "B", "",
    5m, "B", "7",
    6m, "D", "",
    7m, "C", "0",
    8m, "D", "",
    9m, "C", "0"
];
Events
| sort by EventId asc, Time asc




Time
EventId
Value




00:00:00
A
1


00:02:00
A



00:01:00
B
5


00:04:00
B



00:05:00
B
7


00:03:00
C



00:07:00
C
0


00:09:00
C
0


00:06:00
D



00:08:00
D




If you're able to sort your data by a key, and timestamp, then I'd suggest you looking into using prev() or next(). If you sort your data by some key and timestamp, you should be able to look into the next row(s), or previous row(s), and copy their value into the current row.
A few things to keep in mind with this approach:

Although prev() and next() lets you look forwards and backwards, you can only populate/update the values for the current row.
When sorted, if the value in the first row is null for that key (see both C, and D NewValue in the output table below), then that row, and every subsequent row that also has a null value, will never be populated.

You can do something like this:
Events
| sort by EventId asc, Time asc
| extend PrevEventId = prev(EventId), PrevValue = prev(Value)
| extend Value = coalesce(Value, iff(PrevEventId == EventId, PrevValue, Value))
| project-away PrevEventId, PrevValue




Time
EventId
Value




00:00:00
A
1


00:02:00
A
1


00:01:00
B
5


00:04:00
B
5


00:05:00
B
7


00:03:00
C



00:07:00
C
0


00:09:00
C
0


00:06:00
D



00:08:00
D




A few more things to point out from this approach:

We're looking backwards to copy our current value whenever we see null.
On row 4 with EventId as B, if we were to compare timestamps, 7 would have been a closer value to copy from, but we copied 5 instead.
On row 6 with EventId as C, we didn't copy anything.

